# Expression Expected Error - string assign value

Tags: asp.net

Okay, so I got to generate this string to be SHA1 hashed. I have it like this

```
string = "ACCEPTURL=SOMErandomSITE/betaling1.aspxblablaRANDOMNMBRAMOUNT=" & visabedrag3 & "blablaRANDOMNMBRBGCOLOR=#FFFFFFblablaRANDOMNMBRBRAND=VISAblablaRANDOMNMBRBUTTONBGCOLOR=#9BCC83blablaRANDOMNMBRBUTTONTXTCOLOR=#000000blablaRANDOMNMBRCANCELURL=SOMErandomSITE/betaling4.aspxblablaRANDOMNMBRCATALOGURL=SOMErandomSITEblablaRANDOMNMBRCN=" & Session('fac_cntnaam_tsv') Session('fac_cntnaam')Session('bdr_fac_cntnaam_tsv') Session('bdr_fac_cntnaam') & "blablaRANDOMNMBRCOM=Ordernummer " & Shop.Order.Ordernummer & "blablaRANDOMNMBRCURRENCY=EURblablaRANDOMNMBRDECLINEURL=SOMErandomSITE/betaling2.aspxblablaRANDOMNMBREMAIL=" & Session('bdr_fac_cntemail')Session('fac_cntemail') & "blablaRANDOMNMBREXCEPTIONURL=SOMErandomSITE/betaling3.aspxblablaRANDOMNMBRFONTTYPE=arialblablaRANDOMNMBRHOMEURL=SOMErandomSITELANGUAGE=nl_NLblablaRANDOMNMBRLOGO=logo.gifblablaRANDOMNMBRORDERID=" & Shop.Order.Ordernummer & "blablaRANDOMNMBROWNERADDRESS=" & Session('facadres') Session('facadres_nr')Session('bdr_facadres') Session('bdr_facadres_nr') & "blablaRANDOMNMBROWNERZIP=" & Session('facpostcode')Session('facpostcode_letters')Session('bdr_facpostcode')Session('bdr_facpostcode_letters') & "blablaRANDOMNMBRPM=creditcardblablaRANDOMNMBRPSPID=reservecornerblablaRANDOMNMBRTBLBGCOLOR=#ecececblablaRANDOMNMBRTBLTXTCOLOR=#4d4d4dblablaRANDOMNMBRTITLE=Betalen met VisablablaRANDOMNMBRTP=SOMErandomSITE/logo.gifblablaRANDOMNMBRTXTCOLOR=#000000blablaRANDOMNMBR"
```

But the error I get now is  BC30201: Expression expected. What am I doing wrong? It's been years since I've done ASP.net

Comment: Splitting it up, the error is around here: Session('fac_cntnaam_tsv')& " " & Session('fac_cntnaam')&Session('bdr_fac_cntnaam_tsv')&" " & Session('bdr_fac_cntnaam')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed Variable Name

> string sss="value";// In this line(Code) means variable declaration

where,

- **string** means variable data type
- **sss** means variable name
- **"value"** means variable value

try this

```
string data = "ACCEPTURL=SOMErandomSITE/betaling1.aspxblablaRANDOMNMBRAMOUNT=" & visabedrag3 & "blablaRANDOMNMBRBGCOLOR=#FFFFFFblablaRANDOMNMBRBRAND=VISAblablaRANDOMNMBRBUTTONBGCOLOR=#9BCC83blablaRANDOMNMBRBUTTONTXTCOLOR=#000000blablaRANDOMNMBRCANCELURL=SOMErandomSITE/betaling4.aspxblablaRANDOMNMBRCATALOGURL=SOMErandomSITEblablaRANDOMNMBRCN=" & Session('fac_cntnaam_tsv') Session('fac_cntnaam')Session('bdr_fac_cntnaam_tsv') Session('bdr_fac_cntnaam') & "blablaRANDOMNMBRCOM=Ordernummer " & Shop.Order.Ordernummer & "blablaRANDOMNMBRCURRENCY=EURblablaRANDOMNMBRDECLINEURL=SOMErandomSITE/betaling2.aspxblablaRANDOMNMBREMAIL=" & Session('bdr_fac_cntemail')Session('fac_cntemail') & "blablaRANDOMNMBREXCEPTIONURL=SOMErandomSITE/betaling3.aspxblablaRANDOMNMBRFONTTYPE=arialblablaRANDOMNMBRHOMEURL=SOMErandomSITELANGUAGE=nl_NLblablaRANDOMNMBRLOGO=logo.gifblablaRANDOMNMBRORDERID=" & Shop.Order.Ordernummer & "blablaRANDOMNMBROWNERADDRESS=" & Session('facadres') Session('facadres_nr')Session('bdr_facadres') Session('bdr_facadres_nr') & "blablaRANDOMNMBROWNERZIP=" & Session('facpostcode')Session('facpostcode_letters')Session('bdr_facpostcode')Session('bdr_facpostcode_letters') & "blablaRANDOMNMBRPM=creditcardblablaRANDOMNMBRPSPID=reservecornerblablaRANDOMNMBRTBLBGCOLOR=#ecececblablaRANDOMNMBRTBLTXTCOLOR=#4d4d4dblablaRANDOMNMBRTITLE=Betalen met VisablablaRANDOMNMBRTP=SOMErandomSITE/logo.gifblablaRANDOMNMBRTXTCOLOR=#000000blablaRANDOMNMBR"
```

and also you need to concatenation between separate session .

Like & `Session('bdr_fac_cntemail') & Session('fac_cntemail') & Session('bdr_fac_cntemail') & Session('fac_cntemail') & etc`

Not

```
& Session('bdr_fac_cntemail')  Session('fac_cntemail') &
```